# Reduce delay when playing rtp stream with libvlc on Android

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

I am using LibVLC version 3.0.0 to play incoming mpeg2ts stream over rtp on Android. The code is the following:

```
SurfaceView playerView; //Initialized somewhere before    

LibVLC libVlc = new LibVLC(context, arrayListOf("--file-caching=150", "--network-caching=150",
                    "--clock-jitter=0", "--live-caching=150", "--clock-synchro=0",
                    "-vvv", "--drop-late-frames", "--skip-frames"));
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
IVLCVout vout = player.getVLCVout();
vout.setVideoView(playerView);
vout.attachViews();
Media media = new Media(libVlc, Uri.parse("rtp://@:" + UDP_PORT + "/"));
player.setMedia(media);
player.play();
```

This does play the stream, but there is a delay of approximately 2 seconds. I know for certain that the delay can be reduced to ~300 ms as some other player can play it at this delay. Which options should I use to reduce this latency? I understand that I will have to trade quality for it, but how do I do it in the first place?

Comment: can you help me how to integrate camera rtsp stream in flutter

Answer (score 13):

There is a way to reduce the delay from ~2sec to ~200ms

Solution:

```
 ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
 options.add("--file-caching=2000");
 options.add("-vvv");

 LibVLC mLibVLC = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext(), options);
 MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer =  new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);

 Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.1:1935/myApp/myStream"));
        media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
        media.addOption(":network-caching=150");
        media.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
        media.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");

 mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
 mMediaPlayer.play();
```

Hope this help you! =)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I have tried this and it does not seem to be working. What version of LibVLC are you using?

Comment: compile "de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"

Comment: With your code I have managed to reduce delay to ~800 ms. Is it possible to get it down even further?

Comment: Great anwser! With this solution I reduced delay in rtsp stream from ~2s to ~300ms ;)

Comment: I also get delays with 2 sec it is possible to stream without delays  it's a local network

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.

Android:

```
    val options: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    options.add("--file-caching=2000")
    options.add("-vvv")
    options.add("--rtsp-tcp")
```

Flutter:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
final VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController = 
VlcPlayerController.network(
  "rtsp://RTSP_URL_HERE",
  autoPlay: true,
  options: VlcPlayerOptions(
      rtp: VlcRtpOptions([VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(true)])));
```

Comment: This code also working fine  Thanks for post but i am getting bottom black bar its not fitting video view in Surface view can you please help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Using the following as options did the trick for me.

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add("-vvv");
options.add("--rtsp-tcp");
```

LibVLC used:

```
implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3+'
```

Comment: This code also working fine  Thanks for post but i am getting bottom black bar its not fitting video view in Surface view can you please help me what i am doing wrong  URL  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iG9u.png