# React Native VLCPlayer RTSP Latency (Android version)

Tags: android, react-native, vlc, rtsp

I am using [react-native-yz-vlcplayer](https://github.com/xuyuanzhou/react-native-yz-vlcplayer) for a react native application. I have a latency problem on android, the latency is too high. On iOS, I have almost no latency thanks to the plugin options:

```
 mediaOptions={{
 ':network-caching': 0,
 ':live-caching': 0,
 }}
```

I use this plugin to broadcast an RTSP feed.

I don't know how to do that in JAVA.

I also opened an issue on [the player's github](https://github.com/xuyuanzhou/react-native-yz-vlcplayer/issues/39) but no conclusive answer.

I think I need to modify the file [ReactVlcPlayerView.java](https://github.com/xuyuanzhou/react-native-yz-vlcplayer/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/yuanzhou/vlc/vlcplayer/ReactVlcPlayerView.java). I tried to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849541/reduce-delay-when-playing-rtp-stream-with-libvlc-on-android?rq=1), but I couldn't fix the problem, maybe I'm completely wrong but can you help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Share logs please.

Answer (score -1):

thank you for your answer. Here are the logs I'm not sure that's enough for you?

```
02-19 15:56:11.792  9238  9269 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-19 15:56:11.801  9238  9269 D ReactNative: 
ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-19 15:56:12.705  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "JohnDoe" 
with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are 
ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-19 16:02:19.078  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket-0', '_read'
02-19 16:02:19.079  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket-0', 'Socket._read 
resume'
02-19 16:02:19.081  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket-0', 'connecting, 
host:', 'fong.dyndns.tv', 'port:', 6577
02-19 16:02:19.292  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket-0', 'received', 
'connect'
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in Login (at 
navigationStore.js:448)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in Wrapped (at 
SceneView.js:9)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in SceneView (at 
StackViewLayout.js:478)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView (at View.js:43)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView (at View.js:43)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView (at View.js:43)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in AnimatedComponent (at 
screens.native.js:58)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in Screen (at 
StackViewCard.js:42)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in Card (at 
createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
02-19 16:02:19.631  9238  9268 W ReactNativeJS:     in Container (at 
StackViewLayout.js:507)
02-19 16:02:19.939  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: checkInitSuccess
02-19 16:02:20.478  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: 0:0
02-19 16:02:20.640  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: onOpen
02-19 16:02:20.645  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: { type: 'Opening',
02-19 16:02:20.645  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS:   duration: 0,
02-19 16:02:20.645  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS:   currentTime: 0,
02-19 16:02:20.645  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS:   position: 0,
02-19 16:02:20.645  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS:   isPlaying: false }
02-19 16:02:21.353  9238  9268 I ReactNativeJS: onPlaying
```