# How do you prevent any buffering, only show most recent frame with RTSP?

Tags: video, h.264, rtsp, latency, buffering

Are there any hints or other mechanisms with RTSP to make it only show the most recent frame, instead of buffering?  I.e. if there is no smooth motion in the video but need only the most recent frames?  Stuttering is fine, just need frames to be as up to date as possible.  I can add fields to the RTP SDP or other headers.  Just trying to hint to clients like VLC or WMPlayer that it should just play frames up to the most recent one received.

Right now, it accumulates approximately 5 seconds of data, and follows the RTP timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find it is the client hints, as you suggest, that you want to focus on.

For example, VLC contains options to reduce the caching - the following is for reducing the caching from network streams:

> --network-caching=<integer [0 .. 60000]>
> Network caching (ms)
>
> ```
>      Caching value for network resources, in milliseconds.
> ```

(https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

You may also find you need to experiment with several controls to get the right balance of quality and low latency you are looking for and you may also find you need to adjust it depending on the stream and the network.

Its worth looking at other examples to get a feel - e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961321/334402

Also, you will likely not be able to prevent 'any buffering' completely as, depending on the codec used for the video stream, you will need to receive a certain number of packets or frames to allow the decoder on the receiving end start decoding the video and creating the output.